# Article usage in "I want to see ____ (beauty, nature)"

Tags: articles, definite-article, nouns, sentence-choice

> I want to see _______
>   A) beauty of nature
>   B) the beauty of the nature
>   C) the beauty of nature

Which one is correct and why? I have posed this question just to seek proper explanation for the answer.

I think **B** is correct but I don't know why? Only an intution.

Comment: Tells us what you think is correct and why. It will help us know how to help you better if we know what you think.

Comment: @Catija edited.

Comment: I would choose **C**.

Answer (score 1):

If the question isn't referring to some specific nature in some specific place then **"C"** is the correct answer.

Without **"the"** *nature* - is the natural, physical, or material world or universe, and also to life in general.

So: **C)** - I want to see the beauty of nature *(in general)*.